# Custom clip path appbar flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create custom appbar shape as shown in below image. How we can do such shape using clippath?

Tried code:

```
class CustomAppBarShape extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    double height = size.height;
    double width = size.width;
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, size.height),
        radius: Radius.elliptical(30, 10),
    );
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please share what you have done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the desired `AppBar` shape by giving custom shape to the `AppBar` border, check out the live example [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8444950db4f2f09fbe1fdb761a2052bb).

If you want to clip the `AppBar` you can use similar `Path` in the clipper too but I think giving custom shape to the border is better.

code for custom `AppBar` border shape:

```dart
class CustomAppBarShape extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
   @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    double height = rect.height;
    double width = rect.width;
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, height + width * 0.1);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(width * 0.1, height),
        radius: Radius.circular(width * 0.1),
    );
    path.lineTo(width * 0.9,  height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(width, height + width * 0.1),
        radius: Radius.circular(width * 0.1),
    );
    path.lineTo(width,  0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }
}
```

Edit:

For dynamic edge radius update the `customAppBarShape` with the multiplier `multi` as constructor argument, and use `multi` to create outer path.

```dart
class CustomAppBarShape extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
  final double multi;
  const CustomAppBarShape({this.multi = 0.1});
   @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    double height = rect.height;
    double width = rect.width;
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, height + width * multi);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(width * multi, height),
        radius: Radius.circular(width * multi),
    );
    path.lineTo(width * (1 - multi),  height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(width, height + width * multi),
        radius: Radius.circular(width * multi),
    );
    path.lineTo(width,  0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }
}
```

Then send your desired value in constructor parameter like so,

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
   title: Text(widget.title),
   shape: const CustomAppBarShape(multi: 0.02),
)
```

make sure the value of `multi` is less than 1 for desired shape.

Comment: I want to soften the edges less. Is this possible?

Comment: @BurakMeteErdoğan please check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

if you still prefer to use clipper instead of custom shape, you can use my code below for clip image.

```
class BannerClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var height = size.height;
    var width = size.width;

    double radius = 20;

    Path path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, height)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(20, height - 20), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(width - 20, height - 20)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(width, height), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(width, 0)
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```